# , which…to / , to which

Tags: grammar

> I asked him where he was and why he wasn't answering, which he
>   responded that he was fine and he was at home to.
>
> I asked him where he was and why he wasn't answering, to which he
>   responded that he was fine and he was at home.

Which one is the correct one? Do you find the first one clumsy?

Comment: You can end sentences with a preposition, as in *"I asked him a question which he then responded to."* Your first example separates the verb and preposition too much

Comment: Why not take the same wording somewhere such as English Language Learners?

Answer (score -1):

The second phrase is entirely correct. In this case 'to which' refers to the initial clause. You could, redundantly but grammatically, say this:

> I asked him where he was and why he wasn't answering, **to which enquiries** he responded that he was fine and he was at home.

The first phrase is not only clumsy, it's technically ungrammatical: it ends with an unresolved preposition, because the reader expects some object after the 'to'. At home to what?

Comment: I think the use of **to** in the first sentence is just a typo. My guess is it wasn't supposed to be the preposition, but **too**.

Comment: @JasonBassford - yes, that's a possibility to :)

Comment: The first sentence is not really ungrammatical. The preposition at the end clearly has an object—it’s just too far removed from it to be readily parseable. The fact that the preceding complement clause (“that he was at home”) would be reasonably happy to allow a _to_-phrase at the end makes it very easy to misparse the sentence, so it’s definitely a garden-path sentence; but it remains grammatical, albeit very clumsy. @Jason Changing it to _too_ would lead to a completely ungrammatical sentence. “I asked him where he was, which he responded X” is not a complete sentence.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I asked him (1) where he was and (2) why he wasn't answering. He responded that (1) he was fine and (2) he was home. He responded in one way and *also* in another way. He responded that he was home and that he was fine *too*. It's awkward phrasing, but it doesn't seem ungrammatical to me.

Comment: I imagine some serious research has been done on just how far you can separate the preposition from the verb. For example, "I asked him a question which he responded yes to" is readily parsable but the OP absolutely isn't.

Comment: @Jason It’s ungrammatical because you respond _to_ something. Changing the preposition into a _too_ leaves the sentence a preposition short. It’s parallel to saying, “I asked him if he was coming, which he responded yes”, or (to take the example from your second comment) “I asked him a question which he responded yes”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There are many constructions that use **respond** without also using **to**. *"Yes," he responded.* Not, *"Yes," he responded to.* So, *"Yes, " he responded. And then, "No." He responded, "Yes," and "No," too.* You don't need to specify the preposition for it to be correct. In any case, we will have to agree to disagree because comments are not good for this extended explanation. And it's not clear if it was actually a typo anyway.

Comment: @Jason Those are not parallel constructions; they have no oblique object (=question). Note that I said you respond _to_ **something**, where ‘something’ is the oblique object: if there is an oblique object, it must be headed by a preposition (_to_); the direct object is the words uttered (e.g. “yes/no”). In this case, the oblique object is _which_, and its presence means that _to_ is required as well. Removing _to_ would yield two direct objects (“he responded yes the question”), which is ungrammatical. There is absolutely no possibility that it is just a typo.

Comment: Janus Bahs Jacquet, you are exactly right here. The original sentence is the second one, which is "I asked him where he was and why he wasn't answering, to which he responded that he was fine and he was at home.".  I made the first one and made sure it was grammatical, just to see what is the difference between them. And now I know, the first one is just clumsy.

Comment: The "to" at the end of the first sentence, is related to "where he was and why he wasn't answering". If we see "where he was and why he wasn't answering" as two questions, then the "to" at the end of the fist sentence is made for responding to the questions.

Comment: What do you say, Janus?